# Is it possible for a subset of a non-context free language to be context-free?

Tags: subset, context-free-grammar, regular-language

For example, if I have a non-context free language of B, is there such a context free language A such that A is a subset of B? I have been thinking of examples but unable to think of any valid ones.
 I thought I got it when I said that `A = {A = {w | w is of even length and w ∈ {a, b, c}}`, which is context-free, and `B = {ww | w ∈ {a,b,c}}`, which is not context free. However, I realized that there are some strings A can produce that B cannot, and therefore, A is not a subset of B.

Does anyone know of any examples that could be valid in my situation?

Comment: I believe so, but you might want to ask on theory at some other Q&A site since you are not writing a computer program right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any finite set of strings is a context-free language. (Indeed, it is a regular language.) So any finite subset of a language is context-free, regardless of what the language is.

Another trivial case is the language L = L<sub>1</sub> ∪ L<sub>2</sub> where the alphabet of L<sub>1</sub> is Σ<sub>1</sub> and the alphabet of L<sub>2</sub> is Σ<sub>2</sub> and Σ<sub>1</sub> ∩ Σ<sub>2</sub> = ∅. Now L is context-free only if both L<sub>1</sub> and L<sub>2</sub> are context-free. (This is not the case if the alphabets are not disjoint.) So if exactly one of L<sub>1</sub> and L<sub>2</sub> is context-free, then it is a subset of the non-context-free language L.

If neither of those are interesting enough for you, then the language { a* } (where `a` is a symbol) is a subset of { ww | w ∈ {a, b}* }. Another subset of the same classic non-context-free language is { ww | w ∈ {a, b}* ∧ w = w<sup>R</sup> } (that is, the language of all duplicated even-length palindromes) which is context-free because it is exactly the same as { ww<sup>R</sup> | w ∈ {a, b}* ∧ w = w<sup>R</sup> }, as a result of the second condition.